# Silverlight RIA many to many not working

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, many-to-many, ria

I am trying to get a many to many relationship working in RIA/Silverlight, but I can't seem to figure out how.

My database looks like this...

```
Stores     Parts      StoreParts
--------   -------    ----------
ID         ID         StoreID
StoreName  PartName   PartID
```

I create a Entity Data Model on this database.

My XAML looks like this

```
<toolkit:Accordion Background="White" BorderThickness="1" Height="503" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,32,0,0" Name="accordion2" SelectionMode="ZeroOrMore" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181">
    <toolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PartName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:Accordion.ContentTemplate>
    <toolkit:Accordion.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="8" />
    </toolkit:Accordion.Effect>
    <toolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StoreName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:Accordion.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

My XAML code behind:

```
StoreContext storeContext = new StoreContext();
accordion2.ItemsSource = storeContext.Stores;
storeContext.Load(storeContext.GetStoresQuery());
```

My RIA DomainService:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class StoreService : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<MenuTemp2Entities>
{
    public IQueryable<Store> GetStores()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Stores.Include("Parts");
    }
}
```

And, finally, my RIA metadata

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Store.StoreMetadata))]
public partial class Store
{
    internal sealed class StoreMetadata
    {
        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private StoreMetadata()
        {
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("StoreParts", "ID", "ID")]
        public EntityCollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }

        public string StoreName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The StoreName is coming through fine, but it appears that it is not assigning the parts as a sub-table to the store.  It is only returning 1 part per store in the sequence that they are stored in the parts table.  It does not appear to be using the StoreParts relationship at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you declared the metadata for `Part`? Also I think there are other things wrong with your metadata class - I've done something similar myself, but the code's at work so I can't double check and I'd rather not give you false information.

Comment: The metadata is what was auto-generated by Visual Studio, except where I added the [Include] and [Association] tags.  Even if I did create metadata for Part, where would I tell Part to use the metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this Codeplex project it may help.

http://m2m4ria.codeplex.com/